# Is it possible to use Excel 2010 like sparklines in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

I want to know if it possible to repoduce the idea of [Excel 2010 sparklines](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2009/07/17/sparklines-in-excel.aspx) in a SSRS 2005 Report.  I want to show a report that has an indication of the price fluctuations over a 3 month period for a range of products.  I could just give the figures over the 3 month period but it is very hard to quickly distinguish what is happening to the various products in a sea of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://blogs.adatis.co.uk/blogs/timkent/archive/2008/11/06/bullet-charts-and-sparklines-in-reporting-services-2005.aspx), which shows it's possible, and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128%28SQL.90%29.aspx), which although it doesn't mention sparklines explicitly, explains how to embed a chart per-row in a table.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to embed a chart object per line. That's it.

Or programmatically get an Excel sheet from SSRS and enrich it in code.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a third party Sparkline chart control that was originally written for SSRS 2005 - it's been updated for 2008 but I'm pretty sure it still supports SSRS 2005.

I've done a bit of research into embedding Sparklines into a reporting services report and this was what I choose as my solution.  They have a nice fully featured evaluation version which is good for 40 days (I think).

[SparkLines for Reporting Services](http://www.bonavistasystems.com/Products_SparkLinerforMicrosoftBI.html)